# Blank page in wso2 EI as windows service

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I use wso2 EI 6.1.1 installed as windows service with yajsw 11.03 like Installing as a Windows Service document:
    https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service
. But I see a blank page when creating new in sequence in add proxy service menu or add api menu. My problem didn't solve with this config in wrraper.conf:

```
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dwso2.carbon.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\carbon.xml
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dwso2.registry.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\registry.xml
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dwso2.user.mgt.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\user-mgt.xml
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dwso2.transports.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\mgt-transports.xml
wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false wrapper.java.additional.33 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

I changed version of yajsw but wso2 EI don't install as windows service in other yajsw version. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK you can't use yajsw 12.x You need to use 11.03 as you mentioned. Are you getting any error logs while you create a sequence?

Comment: i get this error : IO error excuting tag . JSPException while including path /sequence/design_sequence.jsp . server exception while including page.

Comment: is there any stack trace?

Comment: no, i just see error in wso2carbon.log. error is : ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport} - Error during rendering {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport} javax.servlet.jsp.jspException: IO Error  JSPException while including path /sequence/design_sequence.jsp  -- it works when i use wso2 esb as a bat file not windows service

Comment: This kind of exceptions normally happen,  even esb started from bat file.

Comment: but i can see in sequence create page when esb starts with bat file but not when using windows service